# Can you return Annotations as objects?

Tags: java, type-annotation

Say you wanted to return the version without having to create a variable, or perhaps the serial or reference to something (`@see`), could you do something similar to:

```
public @Version getVersion() {
    return /*the @Version tag on this class*/;
}
```

Where @Version is a runtime-visible annotation declared on the class or method (and for Java 8, Type Annotations)?

Comment: Here is the output and file for the stuff: output: http://pastebin.com/DAsFGDw7 file: http://pastebin.com/tA9DrQtm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but perhaps what you're looking for is something like this:

```
@Version(4)
public class ThisClass {
    public static Version getVersion () {
        return ThisClass.class.getAnnotation(Version.class);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what precise "Version" annotation you're using, or even if this is exactly what you're trying to do, but this certainly seems like a possible answer to the kind of problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much! And now to finish what I started. I was just curious, so by what you have stated I'm guessing you cannot return an Annotation. Anyways, thanks!